# What are the most popular Russian-language chess community websites?

Tags: online-chess, websites

What are the most popular Russian-language chess community websites for high-level chess discussion?

Answer (score 1):

[ChessPro](https://thechessworld.com/articles/cool-chess-things/top-10-most-popular-chess-websites-in-the-world/#:%7E:text=ChessPro.ru,chess%20websites%20in%20the%20world.) is the most popular. Chess.com is next. Chess24 is third.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at ChessPro and Chess24. I know of chess.com already though, and as far as I can tell, there is little Russian-language content and certainly very little high-level chess discussion.

Comment: You asked for what has the most russians. Chess.com is one of them. @Anna

Comment: Apologies about my unclear question, I was wondering about sites in the Russian language. Anyway, thank you for pointing me to ChessPro!

Comment: Okay, then. @Anna